# Divide interval into n parts as evenly as possible

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

How to do this more efficiently? I would think there is a standard quick way to do this. But I just can't find that.

This is for dividing work over some memory between n cpu cores.

Output:

```
# Divide [0, 11) to 4 parts #
interval 0: [0, 3) with length: 3
interval 1: [3, 6) with length: 3
interval 2: [6, 9) with length: 3
interval 3: [9, 11) with length: 2
# Divide [0, 12) to 4 parts #
interval 0: [0, 3) with length: 3
interval 1: [3, 6) with length: 3
interval 2: [6, 9) with length: 3
interval 3: [9, 12) with length: 3
```

Program:

```
#include <iostream>

int part(int L, int n_parts, int part_id) {
    int out = L / n_parts * part_id;
    int r = L % n_parts;
    if (part_id < r) {
        out += part_id;
    } else {
        out += r;
    }
    return out;
}

void test(int L, int n_parts) {
    std::cout << "# Divide [0, " << L << ") to " 
              << n_parts << " parts #\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n_parts; ++i) {
        int st = part(L, n_parts, i);
        int en = part(L, n_parts, i + 1);
        int len = en - st;
        std::cout << "interval " << i <<": [" << st
                  << ", " << en << ") " 
                  << "with length: " << len
                  << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    test(11, 4);
    test(12, 4);
}
```

So far, it uses 1 division, 1 %, 1 multiplication, 1 comparison, and 1 addition (blah for the robot at so).

Comment: if this question get closed, it means there is no faster way.

Comment: I think this question might be more appropriate to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: that place is graveyard. ok for long programs... simple things like this shouldn't take that long.

Comment: I don't understand why you need the `part` function.  Why call it many times?

Comment: Keep `n_parts` a power of 2 and divide/mod and muls turn into faster bitwise operations.

Comment: I have n Cpu, and want to divide the work on a chunk of memory with the length to the n cpus. n isn't always a power of 2.

Comment: Honestly, the work in the threads >>>> work calculating parts.  Slight inefficiency here is noise.

Comment: Am I under thinking this?  Calculate the length of the partition once. In you loop, print the partition start, then add the length to it.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan True, I guess I was 1. bored. 2. just want to know. 3. want to get some down votes and trash this account.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews calculate in worker thread, not in main thread.

Comment: You could calculate the expressions `L/n_parts` and `L%n_parts` only once instead of for each iteration.

Comment: @alain that "test" function is for testing. when i actually use it, i wouldn't do that. Each thread would do that once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually write the solution to these kinds of problems like so:

```
size_t num_of_elements = 10'000;
size_t num_of_groups = 17;
for(size_t i = 0; i < num_of_groups; i++) {
    std::pair<size_t, size_t> pair{
        i * num_of_elements / num_of_groups,
        (i + 1) * num_of_elements / num_of_groups
    };
    std::cout << "Group " << (i+1) << ": [" << pair.first << "," << pair.second << ") - " << (pair.second - pair.first) << " elements." << std::endl;
}
```

This yields the following results if punched into a [mundane `int main()` program](http://ideone.com/MsnWs4):

```
Group 1: [0,588) - 588 elements.
Group 2: [588,1176) - 588 elements.
Group 3: [1176,1764) - 588 elements.
Group 4: [1764,2352) - 588 elements.
Group 5: [2352,2941) - 589 elements.
Group 6: [2941,3529) - 588 elements.
Group 7: [3529,4117) - 588 elements.
Group 8: [4117,4705) - 588 elements.
Group 9: [4705,5294) - 589 elements.
Group 10: [5294,5882) - 588 elements.
Group 11: [5882,6470) - 588 elements.
Group 12: [6470,7058) - 588 elements.
Group 13: [7058,7647) - 589 elements.
Group 14: [7647,8235) - 588 elements.
Group 15: [8235,8823) - 588 elements.
Group 16: [8823,9411) - 588 elements.
Group 17: [9411,10000) - 589 elements.
```

If you want this logic extracted into a function:

```
std::pair<size_t, size_t> get_bounds(size_t group_id, size_t num_of_groups, size_t num_of_elements) {
   return std::make_pair<size_t, size_t>(
       group_id * num_of_elements / num_of_groups,
       (group_id + 1) * num_of_elements / num_of_groups
   );
}
```

Comment: Why is the `vector` needed?  The partitions should be calculated without needing a vector or array (or container).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I've removed it. I copied the code wholecloth from a project I already created and tweaked the variable names without considering that the vector wouldn't be needed here.

Comment: one of the worst cases is 10012

Comment: @rxu Define "Worst" in this context. All groups are assigned either 588 or 589 elements. And no algorithm can divide them all into exactly equal partitions if the number of elements doesn't divide evenly into the number of groups. So any solution using this algorithm must necessarily comprehend that not every group will have the same number of elements, unless you pad the data to a multiple of the number of groups (which comes with its own issues).

Comment: put all of the remainder into one of the parts. or spread remainder evenly between more parts. there is a choice.

Comment: @rxu You can't "spread the remainder evenly", for the reasons I already indicated. What I've done here distributes the work as evenly as is physically possible for any non-fictional computer. And it's not (usually) a good idea to stick all the remainder into the last group, because it will result in a less efficient algorithm for element counts that are significantly larger or smaller than the nearest multiple of the group count. You're working with datasets spread across threads, so this algorithm will [almost] always yield the best distribution of elements across multiple threads.

Comment: @rxu It is possible to optimize this algorithm by trying to make sure that partitions only occur on the boundaries of cache lines, which will result in slightly more uneven group sizes, but might perform better in multithreading scenarios, but that won't always yield a performance advantage (the cases where it will are dubious at best), and in most cases, you're better off simply taking advantage of the optimizations that can be made on easily-read code.

Comment: You are right. My bad. I go to ideone and put in different numbers to test. This is fast and good... let me write a unit test to check if length of all parts differ at most by 1 in all cases.